# Difference between смешнoй and забавный

Tags: значения

These both appear to mean funny or amusing and I was looking for where one was more appropriate than the other. Is *забавный* less comical and more amusing or entertaining while *смешнoй* would be something you'd laugh at a great deal?

Comment: @DK this should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you find that in dictionary two different adjectives are translated similarly, check how dictionary deals with corresponding nouns - sometimes it can give some hints at least.

So, `смех` stand for "laughter", "laugh", `забава` stands for "fun" and "amusement". Similarly, `смеяться` is to laugh, `забавляться` is sort of "to fool with", "to have fun with".

Roughly, "забавный" is something moderately interesting and sort of amusing.

Imagine a movie which is not necessarily funny (may be it's not a comedy at all) but yet is amusing. Imagine a fun (but not funny) and interesting fact, like in phrase:

> Забавный факт - лемминги на самом деле не сигают со скалы для
> контроля популяции.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will do that in the future.